# What API Is Needed To Run A Delphi App from the Start Screen Rather Than The Desktop

Tags: windows, delphi, windows-runtime, delphi-xe4

When you compile and run a Delphi "Metro" app it runs from the Desktop in Windows 8.  What Windows 8 API can make a Delphi app run from the Start Screen?  I am not referring to Windows RT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible. Delphi cannot produce WinRT applications.

Comment: I clarified my post.  I am referring to Windows 8 - 8.1 not Windows RT.

Comment: You are referring to WinRT. What was formerly known as Metro is now known as WinRT. In Win8 there is desktop, and there is WinRT. Delphi can produce apps for desktop, but not WinRT.

Comment: Ok thanks David.  I thought that windows 8 was still windows and RT was the something else entirely.

Comment: Windows 8 desktop is x86/x64 only. WinRT is the funky stuff that used to be Metro, the start screen and what not. WinRT runs on x86/x64/ARM. But Delphi cannot do it. This post from Allen Bauer explains why not: https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=484319#484319

Comment: So I guess we have to wait until an ARM compiler is developed.  I think I read something about that.

Comment: @Bill - 'WinRT' = the name of the 'Metro' API; 'Windows RT' = Windows on ARM (MS' naming department likes to keep people on their toes). As such, WinRT is a part of Windows 8.x on x86/x64 as much as it is a part of Windows RT.

Comment: Well, it's not the ARM that is the problem. And Emba have ARM compilers. The issue is all MS third party restrictions.

Comment: I just looked at the roadmap... at least the latest one I could find and a "Metro" compiler looks like it will not happen this year or even maybe next year...

Comment: Quite plausible that it will never happen. MS would have to open their platform up. C++ or C# are the ways to go for WinRT.

Comment: Oh dear... that is very bad news for Delphi.  I have never been a Delphi is Dead person, but in a few years if Windows 8 takes off Delphi may surly die.

Comment: The desktop isn't going away any time soon. WinRT has been a flop. My guess is that WinRT will die before Delphi. My guess is that WinRT will be swallowed up by Windows Phone.

Comment: @ChrisRolliston _MS' naming department likes to keep people on their toes_ At a Tech Days session we were informed that MS encountered a trademark dispute over the Metro name which is why it was dropped.

Comment: @Craig That is true and widely known. However, they were not compelled to use WinRT and Windows RT to mean different things. I only realised what those terms meant when Chris explained it!